# Why wont lumen recognize fields being sent

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman, lumen

Greeting folks.

I am playing around with a third party api and I have a field required in lumen like:

```
   $this->validate($request, [
            'url' => 'required|string'
        ]);
```

but when I send the url in postman i keep getting that it is not sent

[image]

Anyone knows why it is not recognizing the url sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation form field validation is not supported in lumen could you try json body instead :

body as raw > json

and send

```
{

"url" :"the url"

}
```

[image]